# Add one more property to default Index.cshtml RazorPages Asp.Net Core 2.1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using `Asp.Net Core 2.1.0` in a project where I want to add one extra `property` to default scaffolding `Index.cshtml` page.

Here is my Entities Please suggest.

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRole { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRole { get; set; }
}
public class UserRole
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserName")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the default scaffolding `Index.cshtml` displays `RoleID` and `UserName`where as i want to add one more coloumn i.e `RoleName` which is available at `Role entity`.

List should be `RoleID, RoleName, UserName`

Here is my scaffolding page model.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly Test.Models.TestContext _context;

    public IndexModel(Test.Models.TestContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<UserRole> UserRole { get;set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        UserRole = await _context.UserRole
            .Include(u => u.Role)
            .Include(u => u.User).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Please help me out without disturbing any other pages such as `Edit, Detail, Delete.`

Update: Code in Index.cshtml

```
    @page
@model Test.Pages.UserRoles.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserRole[0].Role)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserRole[0].User)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.UserRole)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role.RoleId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.UserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you show us your `controller` and `index.chtml` code?

Comment: Question is updated with Index.cshtml

Comment: Did you try to use`@item.Role.RoleName` to get your expect ?

Comment: Oh my goodness. I just try this way and results are expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `@item.Role.RoleName` in your `index.chtml`

**Note**

I will suggest you use different `ViewModel` class to carry data for each `view` instead of ModelContext because of ModelContext responsible for getting `DB` data properties to mapper Db tables schema.

`ViewModel` responsible for carrying show data.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) wish can help you